# An ODE with optimal control

Tags: matlab

I am trying to numerically solve an ODE of the form:

```
rV = max(f(a)X + a V') + 1/2 sigma^2 V''
```

where the maximization is done over `a`.  `r` and `sigma` are known parameters, so I'm just trying to find `V(x)`.  The maximization problem is such that I can't simply solve for `a` analytically and plug in that value.

Can MATLAB solve such a problem using ode45?  The online documentation explains how to convert a second-order ODE into a system of first-order ODEs, but I'm not sure how to formulate the problem in this case.